# Service \"AppBundle\\Service\\Report\\Generation\\ACN\" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to get a service from the container

```
 if($responseType == 'json') {
            $generator = $this->container->get('AppBundle\\Service\\Report\\Generation\\ACN');
```

I set it as public

```
  AppBundle\Service\Report\Generation\ACN:
        public: true
```

but the service is not found, do I missed something?

Comment: Try using `ACN::class` (without any quotes). Please note that you will need class `import` for this to work.

Comment: At first glance, I would try removing backslash escaping. You only need this if you pass the string as double-quoted (which you do not)

Comment: Is this code insider of a controller which extends from AbstractController?  If so then the container is not the master container but rather a service locator which holds only a limited number of services.  You really should just inject the service.  If not, use `bin/console debug:container ACN` just to verify your service really does exist and is public.  Maybe you just need a clearing of the cache but probably not.

Comment: I tried with `bin/console debug:container ACN` and the service is public, but I cant get it  with `ACN::class` and removing the backslasch scape neither

Comment: @fg_st And are you using the AbstractController class?

Comment: yes I'm using an AbstractController

Comment: In which case, reread my first comment.  Better yet, take a look at the source code for AbstractController::getSubscribedServices().  As you will be able to see, only a small number of services are available to the controller and yours is not one of them.  This is in fact the major difference between the relatively new AbstractControler and the older/depreciated Controller base class.  You could actually override the method in your controller and add your service but Symfony really does not want you to use Container::get anymore.  May as well accept the fact and inject your service.

Answer (score 0):

you are not supposed to use the container directly. just use DI it will inject all needed automaticly like:

```
use AppBundle\Service\Report\Generation\ACN;

class MyController extends AbstractController 
{
    public function myMethod(ACN $acnGenerator): Response
    {
        $acnGenerator->whatever();

        return new Response('done');
    }
}
```

Or when you need the Generator in many Methods and dont want to inject it anytime you can use (Symfony 4):

```
use AppBundle\Service\Report\Generation\ACN;

class MyController extends AbstractController 
{
    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getSubscribedServices(), [
            ACN::class,
        ]);
    }
    public function myMethod(): Response
    {
        $this->container->get(ACN::class)->whatever();

        return new Response('done');
    }
}
```

Alternativly, on newer Symfony version, with Attributes:

```
use Symfony\Contracts\Service\Attribute\Required;
use AppBundle\Service\Report\Generation\ACN;

class MyController extends AbstractController
{
  #[Required]
  public ACN $acnGenerator;

  public function myMethod(): Response
  {
      $this->acnGenerator->whatever();
      return new Response('ok');

  }
}
```